# IPTables how to nat 10.8.a.b to 10.0.a.b?

Tags: nat, dnat

## The problem -- Translate 10.8.a.b to 10.0.a.b ?

I have a VPN setup to a bastion host. I'm attempting to map `10.8.0.0/17` into `10.0.0.0/17` so that the IP address `10.8.1.1` gets mapped to `10.0.1.1` in my local network.

I imagine the culprit of this problem is

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 10.8.0.0/17 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.0-10.0.127.255
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
####
# This allows you to DNAT connections in a round-robin way over a given range of destination addresses.
# --to-destination ipaddr-ipaddr
#     Address range to round-robin over.
```

```
# What I Want:
#    10.8.0.1 -> 10.0.0.253 -> 10.0.0.1
# What I Get:
listening on tun0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), snapshot length 262144 bytes
04:41:15.934726 IP 10.8.255.1 > 10.8.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 93, seq 1, length 64

listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
05:50:27.228399 IP 10.0.0.253 > 10.0.52.24: ICMP echo request, id 93, seq 1, length 64
                                ^^^^^^^^^^
                              Wrong IP Address!!!
```

How do I write the (first 17 bit/last 15 bits) of the destination into a new destination.
A more clear example of what I'm aiming to achieve is **10.8.0.100** in the VPN correlates to **10.0.0.100** in my LAN network.

Note: This is my first time setting up routing between two networks, if there's any obvious mistakes or inconsistency with normal conventions please address it, I'm still learning.
IPTables how to nat 10.8.a.b to 10.0.a.b?

## Networks

## LAN (10.0.0.0/16)

| network | VPN IP |
| --- | --- |
| **10.0.0.1** | ISP Gateway |
| **10.0.0.253** | Home OpenVPN Gateway (**10.8.255.2**) |

## VPN (10.8.0.0/16)

| network | VPN IP |
| --- | --- |
| **10.8.0.0/16** | Reserved Clients (Start at **10.8.128.1**) |
| **10.8.0.0/17** | IP Forward NAT **10.8.0.0/17 -> 10.0.0.0/17 via 10.8.255.2** |
| **10.8.255.1** | Cloud Server Gateway |
| **10.8.255.2** | Home OpenVPN Gateway (LAN: **10.0.0.253**) |

#### VPN Routes

| network | gateway | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **10.8.0.0/16** | **10.8.255.1** | Entire network |
| **10.8.0.0/17** | **10.8.255.2** | all IP address should translate the last 15 bits onto the destination (**10.8.0.100 -> 10.0.0.100**) |

## IPTables

```
root@gwhome# iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
root@gwhome# iptables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
root@gwhome# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
root@gwhome# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 10.8.0.0/17 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.0-10.0.127.255
```

**This machine is not the network gateway**, so I've seen some people mention the need for `SNAT`, but I think the need for this should be alleviated by `MASQUERADE`. A confirmation on this would be appreciated.

### ping 10.8.0.1 (LAN: 10.0.0.1)

```
root@cloud-server# ping 10.8.0.1 -c 3
PING 10.8.0.1 (10.8.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 10.8.0.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2078ms
```

### tun0 sniff

```
root@gwhome# tcpdump -i tun0 icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on tun0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), snapshot length 262144 bytes
04:41:15.934726 IP 10.8.255.1 > 10.8.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 89, seq 1, length 64
04:41:16.989078 IP 10.8.255.1 > 10.8.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 89, seq 2, length 64
04:41:18.013008 IP 10.8.255.1 > 10.8.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 89, seq 3, length 64
^C
3 packets captured
3 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

### eth0 sniff

```
root@gwhome# tcpdump -i eth0 icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
05:50:27.228399 IP 10.0.0.253 > 10.0.52.24: ICMP echo request, id 93, seq 1, length 64
05:50:28.234007 IP 10.0.0.253 > 10.0.52.24: ICMP echo request, id 93, seq 2, length 64
05:50:29.257588 IP 10.0.0.253 > 10.0.52.24: ICMP echo request, id 93, seq 3, length 64
^C
3 packets captured
3 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

Comment: Simply put, you *don't NAT* between private addresses. You simply route. However, host configurations/issues are explicitly off-topic here, see the [help/on-topic]. You might want to try on [su] or on [sf] for an on-topic business network.

Comment: You can use `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 1.2.3.0/24 -j NETMAP --to 5.6.7.0/24`. This avoids to create 256 DNAT rules manually when all you want is 1:1 mapping.

Comment: The natural way would be to use routing. But NETMAP with MASQUERADE SNAT have the advantage of being totally invisible from the dest network perspective, you only need one sneaky host collaborating (which is not the gateway) and you don't need to change any configuration of any other host.

Comment: If however you have access to the gateway in the dest network, you don't really need NETMAP: you can use routing. Just keep all hosts default gw the same (router) but tell router to give packets to VPN gateway. But if you can't touch the gw, NETMAP is a funny tool to overcome that. It's just it's kind of sneaky and makes debugging a bit difficult because we are "abusing identity" and trick dest hosts.